# CakePHP: How do i use Set::contains to compare subsets of Arrays to a given Array?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following array, named $usergrouppermissions:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [UserGroupPermission] => Array
                (
                    [group_id] => 1
                    [permission_id] => 4
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [UserGroupPermission] => Array
                (
                    [group_id] => 1
                    [permission_id] => 5
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [UserGroupPermission] => Array
                (
                    [group_id] => 1
                    [permission_id] => 6
                )

        )

    [3] => Array


[...]
```

In a loop, i build another array like this, named $searchme:

```
Array
(
    [UserGroupPermission] => Array
        (
            [permission_id] => 1
            [group_id] => 1
        )

)
```

Now, i want to check, if given array above exists in the numeric-indexed array at the top. I currently do this:

```
$result = Set::contains($usergrouppermissions, $searchme);
```

The result is always false. Do i get something wrong here? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PH 4.2 in_array can also use arrays as needle. So, the solution is this:

```
in_array($searchme, $usergrouppermissions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm very late with this answer, but here it is anyway for future generations :)

The cake way would be:

```
$exists = Set::matches
    (
        sprintf
        (
            '/UserGroupPermission[group_id=%s][permission_id=%s]',
            $searchme['UserGroupPermission']['group_id'],
            $searchme['UserGroupPermission']['permission_id']
        ),
        $usergrouppermissions
    );
```

If you take a look at the code of `Set::contains()` you will see it doesn't work well with nested contains (at least not in your case).

`Set::matches()` basically just calls `Set::extract()` with the XPath condition given and turns the result into a bool value for your pleasure.